# Artifactory error on eclipse: Error code 502, cannot connect

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy, artifactory

I am using Artifactory for jar downloading and uploading jars.
But it gives me below error while deploying jar to the Artifactory server through eclipse run configurations.

command: `clean install deploy`

Error:

> **Error code 502, cannotconnect**

I have setup my proxies also.
My settings file is having all the necessary things for Artifactory.

Comment: First network issue... furthermore why using `clean install deploy`? Does not make sense...

Comment: A 502 status is usually not something you can fix in code. It's a server or networking issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise. We need to  deploy the jar from the local eclipse, so i am using this command.

Comment: That makes the command not correct because you are repeating a lot of stuff... usually `mvn deploy` is sufficient... Please check the documentation about the life cycle in Maven...